# recursively removing permissions under root folder

Tags: linux, permissions

i am new to linux platform and now i wanted to remove write permissions of all the php files under my root folder. It would be appreciable if somebody can suggest a solution.

thanks and regards

tismon

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

```
find / -name '*.php' -exec chmod a-w {} \;
```

Comment: before you do that, you can also use 'find /root -name *.php -print' (remove the quotes) to see what files it will change permissions to. Also, you'll probably want to use sudo to run that command with root permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am afraid to say that the command is not working with my system (RHEL 5). It would be helpful if you could provide an alternate option.

Comment: You have to put the \*.php in quotes like this: find / -name "\*.php" -exec chmod a-w {} \;

Answer (score 0):

An alternate option would be to use these 2 commands

```
cd /
chmod -R a-w *.php
```

But I also recommend (like Matthieu did) to have a look first, what files you are really modifying.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
find /root -type f -name "*php" | xargs chmod 664
```